# Get next page URL

Tags: python, loops, beautifulsoup

Now I tried to scrape all the URLs from a web page. It totally has 5 categories, and every category has different pages (Every page has 10 articles).

For example:

```
Categories   Pages
Banana          5
Apple          14
Cherry          7
Melon           6
Berry           2
```

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from urllib.parse import urljoin


res = requests.get('http://www.abcde.com/SearchParts')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
href = [ a["href"] for a in soup.findAll("a", {"id" : re.compile("parts_img.*")})]
b1 =[]
for url in href:
    b1.append("http://www.abcde.com"+url)
print (b1)
```

From main page "http://www.abcde.com/SearchParts" I can scrape first page's URL of every category. B1 is the list of first page's URLs.

Like this:

```
Categories   Pages                       url
Banana          1     http://www.abcde.com/A
Apple           1     http://www.abcde.com/B
Cherry          1     http://www.abcde.com/C
Melon           1     http://www.abcde.com/E
Berry           1     http://www.abcde.com/F
```

Then I use b1's source code to scrape next page's URLs. So b2 is the list of second page's URL.

Code:

```
b2=[]
for url in b1:
    res2 = requests.get(url).text
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(res2,"lxml")
    url_n=soup2.find('',rel = 'next')['href']
    b2.append("http://www.abcde.com"+url_n)
print(b2)
```

Like this:

```
Categories   Pages                       url
    Banana          1     http://www.abcde.com/A/s=1&page=2
    Apple           1     http://www.abcde.com/B/s=9&page=2
    Cherry          1     http://www.abcde.com/C/s=11&page=2
    Melon           1     http://www.abcde.com/E/s=7&page=2
    Berry           1     http://www.abcde.com/F/s=5&page=2
```

Now when I try to do the third one, it's an error since Berry's second page is the last page, it has no "next" in the source code. What should I do especially when every category has different pages/URLs?

Entire code (until it got error):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from urllib.parse import urljoin


res = requests.get('http://www.ca2-health.com/frontend/SearchParts')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
href = [ a["href"] for a in soup.findAll("a", {"id" : re.compile("parts_img.*")})]
b1 =[]
for url in href:
    b1.append("http://www.ca2-health.com"+url)
print (b1)
print("===================================================")
b2=[]
for url in b1:
    res2 = requests.get(url).text
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(res2,"lxml")
    url_n=soup2.find('',rel = 'next')['href']
    b2.append("http://www.ca2-health.com"+url_n)
print(b2)
print("===================================================")
b3=[]
for url in b2:
    res3 = requests.get(url).text
    soup3 = BeautifulSoup(res3,"lxml")
    url_n=soup3.find('',rel = 'next')['href']
    b3.append("http://www.ca2-health.com"+url_n)
print(b3)
```

And after this, I will make b1, b2, b3 and... As a list since then I will have all the URLs from this page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you're getting a `KeyError`. Handle the exception and continue the loop. If you're getting `KeyError` do the following:

```
try:
    url_n = soup3.find(rel='next')['href']
except KeyError:
    continue
```

**OR**

```
try:
    url_n = soup3.find(rel='next').get('href')
except AttributeError:
    continue
```